# Cannot get a connection, pool exhausted on a single host

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

I have a service deployed on multiple EC2 hosts. 1 host starts throwing errors. The max connections allowed are 5 and at the time of outage I could see the number of active connectives to be 2. IT would have made sense if the outage was across all hosts but I am not able to understand what caused the issue on a single host.

DB was able to provide connections. If this is a host issue, how should I resolve this?

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open
>   connection | at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
>   | at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
>   | at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
>   | at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
>   | at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
>   | at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
>   | at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160) |
>   at
>   org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
>   | at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
>   | at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:560)
>   | ... 26 more | Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException:
>   Cannot get a connection, pool exhausted | at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:103)
>   | at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:540)
>   | at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:85)
>   | at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
>   | ... 31 more | Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout
>   waiting for idle object | at
>   org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:756)
>   | at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:95)
>   | ... 34 more },

Comment: What is your application server? Are you using tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

You said, " The max connections allowed are 5 and at the time of outage I could see the number of active connectives to be 2."   How do you see the number of connections at the time of the failure?

If you're able to do a little experiment, you could try increasing the connection pool size and see what happens.